# SecureFunction.apply removes methods of 'this' object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

Some of my lightning event parameters are functions ( to manage callBack using a dispatcher component).

As the function is passed thru events, it is converted in a "SecureFunction" by LockerService.

In the following code, **function isSuccess is filtered by SecureFunction.call** whereas it shouldn't.

```
    var callBack = event.getParam('callBack');        
    var  obj = new Object();
    obj.isSuccess = function()
    {
       return true ;
    }
    callBack.call(this,obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

We are looking into this - something similar was already under investigation (by me in fact). You can reference bug **W-3331939** in any communications with support etc to help keep everyone one in the lop. This one is a bit of a challenge because SecureFunction is a closure that captures the original ***this*** on purpose to protect against malicious injection attacks via ***this*** spoofing.

Comment: Any news ? :) I can't reactivate LockerService while it's not solved , i'm afraid before that the team develops stuff that will crash with LS activated ^^